# PermitRootLogin set to no but can still use root on Centos Stream 9

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos, ssh, redhat

Im following an RHCSA training course and to disable root I need to set PermitRootLogin to no in the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file and restart sshd using systemctl. I've done all this and can still login as root. Can anyone tell me what to do? Thanks.

Output of `ps`:

```
root         836       1  0 14:36 ?        00:00:00 sshd: /usr/sbin/sshd -D [listener] 0 of 10-100 startups
root        3929    2956  0 15:03 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto ssh
```

Content of `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
#RekeyLimit default none
#SyslogFacility AUTH
#LogLevel INFO
#LoginGraceTime 2m
PermitRootLogin no
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10
#PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile  .ssh/authorized_keys
#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none
#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody
#HostbasedAuthentication no
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
#IgnoreRhosts yes
#PasswordAuthentication yes
#PermitEmptyPasswords no
#KbdInteractiveAuthentication yes
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken no
#KerberosUseKuserok yes
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
#GSSAPIStrictAcceptorCheck yes
#GSSAPIKeyExchange no
#GSSAPIEnablek5users no
#UsePAM no
#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
#X11Forwarding no
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PermitTTY yes
#PrintMotd yes
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS no
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none
#Banner none
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
#Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#Setting timeout interval
ClientAliveInterval 600
ClientAliveCountMax 0
```

Comment: Can you paste the contents of your `sshd_config` file (minus comments and blank lines) here in the question, along with the output of `ps -fe |grep ssh`?

Comment: did you closed all open ssh connections?

Comment: Hi, Ive added the contents of SSHD config and done the grep.

Comment: Any changes I make to the sshd_config file do not work, even if I restart the server.

Comment: when you mention "i can still login", you are logging in through SSH right ? not through the system "console" ?

Comment: I can still login through both.

Answer (score 1):

Check files in /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*
Maybe there are directives “PermitRootLogin yes”

On CentOS 9 i have “PermitRootLogin yes” in files
/etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/50-redhat.conf
/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/01-permitrootlogin.conf